# How do I detect the type of camera installed?

Tags: hardware, camera

I need to know how to remotely detect whether an 8mp or a 5mp camera module is connected to the rpi for implementation in an embedded project.

Any help?

Comment: Why not look up the camera specs online?

Comment: The device itself will be inaccessible and so I need to identify the model of the camera though ssh.

Comment: Take a picture and look at resolution/size? Should be significantly different.

Comment: Is there a cli command to see the dimensions of an image? If so then I could just pipe the output of raspistill into that info command.

Comment: get some inspiration here http://superuser.com/questions/275502/how-to-get-information-about-an-image-picture-from-the-linux-command-line and here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75635/shell-command-to-get-pixel-size-of-an-image

Answer (score 8):

None of the above.

Take advantage of the v4l driver (`modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`), and either use the `v4l2-ctl` command from the CLI, or, if you want to get fancy, use the v4l2 libraries from python or C:

```
# v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YU12'
        Name        : Planar YUV 4:2:0
```

(much more output)

```
# v4l2-ctl --list-framesizes=YU12
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FRAMESIZES
        Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
```

Comment: The actual question is apparently how can I get V412-ctl? With me it just says "no such file or directory".  "Unable to locate package  v412-ct" Without this information the answer is incomplete.

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst - The key is that it is `v4l2-ctl`, not `v412-ctl`.  That's a lowercase L after the 4, not a 1.  It appears to have come preinstalled on a totally-stock raspbian for a pi zero I just opened.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me.  With Raspbian Stretch (June 2018 Version, Kernel 4.14), Python 3.5 and picamera 1.13 I used:

```
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
    print(cam.revision)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy coding C, have a look at the [relevant lines in raspistill](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiStill.c#L276) which uses the new `MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_INFO` to look up the type of camera attached.

If you're not so happy with C, you'll need to wait a week or so while I finish off picamera 1.11 which will have a new `PiCamera.model` parameter you can query for the same information (this will return a string containing the sensor name as returned by `MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_INFO`).

**Update**
As EdMc2's answer neatly shows, I wound up calling this `PiCamera.revision` rather than model!

Comment: Thanks for the update!  This post shows up first in a search for 'picamera get model' so I'm grateful for the breadcrumbs

Answer (score 2):

EdMc2's answer worked for me--but cam.revision only display camera sensor name. So I did find maximum resolution like this:

```
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
    print(cam.MAX_RESOLUTION)
```

You can save the file (for example, picamera.py) and execute it like this:

```
python3 picamera.py
```

My result is `2592x1944` which is 5MP camera.