# Differentiate between pi cam v1 and v2

Tags: camera

I'm writing a program for the pi I need to know if the user uses a pi cam v1 or the V2 is there a known way to tell the difference.
I don't mind going low level (c or c++) if I have to

Comment: I'd take a look at the image resolution. V1 has 5 MegaPixel while V2 has 8. https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/

Answer (score 2):

You can get the revision number by this Python code:

```
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
    print(cam.revision)
```

`picamera`'s `revision` returns a string representing the revision of the Pi's camera module. At the time of writing, the string returned is `ov5647` for the **V1** module, and `imx219` for the **V2** module.

---

Related links:
[The PiCamera Class](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_camera.html)
[How do I detect the type of camera installed?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46632/how-do-i-detect-the-type-of-camera-installed)

Comment: is there a way to get that from the /sys directory

Comment: @oriagranat9 I don't think so. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146886#p993283